# Details of multiple commit at once

Tags: git

I have today a machinery that is able to read single commit details using `git rev-list`, e.g.

```bash
$ git rev-list --timestamp --max-count=1 {hash}
```

However I may have more than one commit to get details from. And as such I would like to reduce the invocation of the `git` command, which is called from another runtime.

I didn't found a way to use `git rev-list` so that only the references are passed are printed.

Something like that

```bash
$ git rev-list <the correct options> --timestamp --pretty=oneline {H1} {H2} ... {Hn}
1688476824 f670d3bf2b845b526ec99e4ef4dfbe25532023bd chore: work 1
1688476399 f90b69ef94a69fc905233179ef8cc58aaeed3ebb chore: work 2
...
1688474513 b93876fb4665d9cc343e03f763f5a24dda63e85f chore: work n
```

Unfortunately my attempts made `git rev-list` print all previous commits.

Note `--max-count` applies to the whole output it seems like `head -n 1`.

If this is possible with `git` commands, I'd like to know how.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `--no-walk` so only the last commits of your refs would be printed, don't forget to remove the `-n1` or `--max-count=1` option.

You can add `unsorted` value to the option so the commits would be listed the same order as refs (could be useful for automation).

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---no-walksortedunsorted

```
$ git rev-list --timestamp --pretty=oneline --no-walk=unsorted master dev dev2
1688456154 cbf93280b240df1d5c586729c6c32c96b4f38788 Merge branch 'release'
1686825873 48c81eb8da3f97703d86241303faec1aa04c1b14 Merge branch 'release'
1686825932 a1b25897c07edce5f872149857d81c9b638892cc merge from dev into dev2
```

Comment: And there's the `--stdin` to feed the list in that way.

Comment: @jthill i guess the OP already uses some scripting...